# No return statement warning in function returning non-void

Tags: c++, oop, static

This is lines of my code that I get a warning  saying "No return statement warning in function returning non-void" I have declared total as: static int total;

```
int Rooms::getTotalEmptyRooms() {
    return total;
}
int Rooms::setTotalEmptyRooms(int i) { //warning here
    total = i;
}
```

Any suggestion how can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: This warning is saying you're being inconsistent.Your function saying it's going to return an int, *and* that it's not returning an int. You *must* choose one or the other, you can't have both.

Comment: @HANA What is unclear with the message?

Comment: Which part of the warning do you not get? The lack of a `return` statement in `setTotalEmptyRooms`? The use of "function returning non-void" to describe `setTotalEmptyRooms`? Something else?

Comment: It's dangerous to declare a non-return statement to a non-void function (that's why the warning) , your function as `int-return` must have an integer output. So, add `return total;` or change your function into a `void`, knowing that `total` is an attribute, so it can be considered as a mutator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare it as an *int*, it has to have *return* with an in inside the function.

Either change the head to

```
void Rooms::setTotalEmptyRooms(int i) {
    total = i;
}
```

or have it return something, like

```
int Rooms::setTotalEmptyRooms(int i) {
    total = i;
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add return statement to the function or change the signature to void

```
int Rooms::setTotalEmptyRooms(int i)
{
    total = i;
    return somthing;
}
```

or

```
void Rooms::setTotalEmptyRooms(int i)
{
        total = i;
}
```

Comment: no declaration matches 'void Rooms::setTotalEmptyRooms(int)' I get this error with the second suggest.

Comment: If you get the no declaration error then you need to change the return type in declaration in the class

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared to return `int`. But there's no `return` statement in the function that does so.